# Does iOS storyboards have layout resource files like android?

Tags: android, ios, storyboard

I'm from the android background. I don't know about iOS. In Android, Views are created using XML files. I have seen the storyboard, there only option to work on the design and no option to see storyboard files like an Android. Please excuse me. If I'm unable to convey my query properly.

I have built an App using Kotlin, XML using the Android Studio. Now I'm building the same app in Xcode. I have seen this new kind of development.

Comment: You can use `xib` files

Comment: The storyboards are nothing but XML files, Select storyboard right click and open as source code. It will show storyboard as an XML format.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The storyboard file is an abstraction design image of XML internally.

You can check xml code in storyboard with clicking right button of mouse with storyboard file in xcode. maybe [show code?]

**But, xml of storyboard file is too complex to understand than Android.**

There is no guide about how to dealing storyboard with xml.

Because It is not normal way.

in iOS, you can design your layout in three way.

1. Use Interface builder of storyboard
2. Using code with programmatically adjusting auto layout(SnapKit is good library for this work)
3. using xib file

Answer (score 2):

in Android you are able to write `.xml` to design and layout. In iOS you are able to design using Interface builder of storyboard which create not readable `.xib` file. Yes it is possible to edit this file but it is not simple task. That is one create merge conflicts

Answer (score 1):

You can create an app without using a storyboard as well by the code only. But for doing that, you need to have a good understanding of Swift language and Layout Constraints to develop an app using code only. As you are new to XCode, I will suggest you to develop using Storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to use Storyboards, it’s easy to learn and even better than xml layout design, because you can position Views like if you were working on Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS Storyboard and XIB both options are good for design but I prefer Storyboard first because it is very simple and easy to use.

In iOS, you can do programming same like Android.

[image]

You can add your resource in `Assets.xcassets` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in both way, using storyboard or by only coding. I prefer coding instead of storyboard, it may improve your iOS layout knowledge.